# how can I put validation if the record is inserted today?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$days = date('Y-m-d ', mktime($count['time_in']));
$date_today = date('Y-m-d');

if ($days != $date_today)  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login_details (time_in, user_id) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."') ";
    $result =  mysql_query($sql);

} else{         
   echo "<h3 align=center>Already exist!</h3>";
   header ('refresh: 3; URL = index.php?page=timerecord');
}
```

Comment: You want to validate if `user id` was inserted before?

Comment: It would be awesome to check if the record has been inserted tomorow

Comment: Not `has been` but `will be`.

Comment: check if the row is inserted today

Comment: if I inserted data today i cannot insert data again today so it will be valid on the next day

Comment: @u_mulder Everything is relative... Anyway, what is "validation" ?

Comment: just select the time in between today and tomorrow according to user id. it will depend on how your dates are saved. `datetime`, unix time, et.c

Comment: @Brewal Not everything is relative in terms of web. Validation is testing user input against known constraints.

Comment: @bad_boy come on don't be so serious !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

time_in column should be in database should be datetime data type.

```
$date_today = date('Y-m-d');

$selectSql=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as logincount from login_details where time_in=date(now())");
$countLogin=mysql_result($selectSql,0,'logincount');

if($countLogin>0){
} else {
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_details (time_in, user_id) VALUES ('".$date_today."', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."')");
}
```

Comment: August 26,2014 12:00:00 am  this is the output on my time in record

Comment: can you say how the input and output will be with example?

Comment: just like a DAILY TIME RECORD for every user

Comment: how can i improve my answers.

Comment: you looking like this: where date(time_in)=date(now()) and user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';

Comment: im looking for the current date and time

Comment: date(time_in)=date(now()) is enough, If the record is inserted today? change time_in datatype to datetime.

Comment: the date is inserting at my database but the time wont so the output is 12:00 am

Comment: how to add? where s that option found?

Comment: same questions i think